# Validar formulario de cada pestaña del wizard al darle clic al botón siguiente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo una duda con una modal que tengo, dentro de la modal se encuentra un wizard con diferentes formularios. Mi duda es como podría validar cada uno de los formularios, al dar siguiente se validaría el formulario y si todo es correcto pasaría a la siguiente pestaña del wizard. Para las validaciones estoy utilizando jquery valídate.

Les anexo mi código para que me den lluvia de ideas de cómo hacerlo.

> Nuevo Código

```js
let reglas = {

    '1': { rules: {
          "form-usu-docente-matricula-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nombre-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ap-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-am-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-curp-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ss-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-rfc-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nacion-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ife-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ln-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-fn-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-sexo-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nt-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-mailp-add": {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }

        },
        messages: {
          "form-usu-docente-matricula-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Matrícula"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nombre-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Nombre(s)"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ap-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Apellido Paterno"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-am-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Apellido Materno"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-curp-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar CURP"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ss-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Seguro Social"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-rfc-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar RFC"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nacion-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Nacionalidad"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ife-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar IFE"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ln-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Lugar de Nacimiento."
          },
          "form-usu-docente-fn-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Fecha de Nacimiento"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-sexo-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Sexo"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nt-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Número de Tarjeta"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-mailp-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Correo Personal"
          }

        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
          element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        }},
    '2': { rules: {
          "form-usu-docente-estado-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-municipio-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-colonia-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-calle-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ne-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ni-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-telefono-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-celular-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-cp-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          "form-usu-docente-estado-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Estado"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-municipio-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Municipio"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-colonia-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Colonia"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-calle-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Calle"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ne-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Número Exterior"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ni-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Número Interior"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-telefono-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Teléfono"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-celular-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Celular"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-cp-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Código Postal"
          }
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
          element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        }}
  };

  function formValidate(num) {
    if(reglas[num]) {
        $('#modal-form-add-docente').validate(reglas[num]);
        console.log($('#modal-form-add-docente').validate().settings.rules);
        let valid = $('#modal-form-add-docente').valid();
        $('#modal-form-add-docente').validate().destroy();
        return valid;
    }
    return true;
}


  function wizard_docente(wizard){

    switch (wizard) {
      case "s_menu1":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "s_menu2":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "r_menu2":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "s_menu3":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "r_menu3":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "s_menu4":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "r_menu4":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      case "r_menu5":
        wizard_posicion_docente(wizard);
        break;
      default:
        alert("default");
        break;
    }
  }

  function wizard_posicion_docente(posicion){
    // Separar en partes para saber qué hacer
        // prevNext puede ser "s" (siguiente) o "r" (regresar)
        // current es el número de menú actual
        let [prevNext, current] = posicion.split('_menu');
        // Cuál es la siguiente pestaña a mostrar
        let next;
        
        if(prevNext == 'r') {
            // Es retroceso, no requiere validar formulario
            // Retroceder solo si la sección actual es mayor que uno
            next = (current > 1) ? current - 1 : current;
        } else {
            // Es avance, se debe validar formulario
            if(!formValidate(current)) {
                // Falló la validación, no ir al siguiente
                return;
            }
            // Pasar a siguiente pestaña solo si no estás en la última
            next = (current < 5) ? parseInt(current) + 1 : current;
        }
        if(next == current) {
          // Es el mismo, no es necesario hacer cambios
          return;
        }
        // Ocultar sección actual
        $('#menu' + current).removeClass('active');
        $('#menu' + current).removeClass('show');
        $('#m_menu' + current).removeClass('active');

        // Mostrar anterior o siguiente
        $('#menu' + next).addClass('active');
        $('#menu' + next).addClass('show');
        $('#m_menu' + next).addClass('active');
  }
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-docente">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="titulo-modal-docente">Agregar Administrador</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- form start -->
          <form id="modal-form-add-docente">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="container">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="m_menu1">Inf. Personal</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu2">Inf. Personal</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu3">Financiera</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu4">Academica</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu5">Dirección</a>
                  </li>
                </ul> 

                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ID / Matrícula</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-matricula-add" name="form-usu-docente-matricula-add" placeholder="Matrícula" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nombre(s)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-nombre-add" name="form-usu-docente-nombre-add" placeholder="Nombre(s)">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ap-add" name="form-usu-docente-ap-add" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Apellido Materno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-am-add" name="form-usu-docente-am-add" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CURP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-curp-add" name="form-usu-docente-curp-add" placeholder="CURP">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Seguro Social</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ss-add" name="form-usu-docente-ss-add" placeholder="Seguro Social">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">RFC</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-rfc-add" name="form-usu-docente-rfc-add" placeholder="RFC">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nacionalidad</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-nacion-add" name="form-usu-docente-nacion-add" placeholder="Nacionalidad">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">IFE</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ife-add" name="form-usu-docente-ife-add" placeholder="IFE">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Lugar de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ln-add" name="form-usu-docente-ln-add" placeholder="Lugar de Nacimiento">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-fn-add" name="form-usu-docente-fn-add" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Sexo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-sexo-add" name="form-usu-docente-sexo-add" placeholder="Sexo">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Número de Tarjeta</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-nt-add" name="form-usu-docente-nt-add" placeholder="Número de Tarjeta">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Correo Personal</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-mailp-add" name="form-usu-docente-mailp-add" placeholder="Correo Personal">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu1" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)" disabled="true"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu1" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Numero 2 -->
                  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Estado</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-estado-add" name="form-usu-docente-estado-add" placeholder="Estado">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Municipio</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" name="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" placeholder="Municipio">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Colonia</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" name="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" placeholder="Colonia">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Calle</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-calle-add" name="form-usu-docente-calle-add" placeholder="Calle">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Número Exterior</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ne-add" name="form-usu-docente-ne-add" placeholder="Número Exterior">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Número Interior</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ni-add" name="form-usu-docente-ni-add" placeholder="Número Interior">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" name="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" placeholder="Teléfono">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Celular</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-celular-add" name="form-usu-docente-celular-add" placeholder="Celular">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">C.P.</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-cp-add" name="form-usu-docente-cp-add" placeholder="C.P.">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu2" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu2" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Numero 3 -->
                  <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tabulador</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-cp-add" name="form-usu-docente-cp-add" placeholder="C.P.">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tabulador 2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" name="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" placeholder="Municipio">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Percepción Única</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" name="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" placeholder="Colonia">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Clave Bancaria</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-calle-add" name="form-usu-docente-calle-add" placeholder="Calle">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre Banco</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ne-add" name="form-usu-docente-ne-add" placeholder="Número Exterior">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Cuenta</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ni-add" name="form-usu-docente-ni-add" placeholder="Número Interior">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Actividad Primordial</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" name="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" placeholder="Teléfono">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Dirección de Actividad Primordial</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-celular-add" name="form-usu-docente-celular-add" placeholder="Celular">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Teléfono de Actividad Primordial</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" name="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" placeholder="Teléfono">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu3" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu3" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Numero 4 -->
                  <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Titulo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-cp-add" name="form-usu-docente-cp-add" placeholder="C.P.">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Grado</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" name="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" placeholder="Municipio">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cedula</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" name="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" placeholder="Colonia">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Año de entrada</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-calle-add" name="form-usu-docente-calle-add" placeholder="Calle">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Turno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ne-add" name="form-usu-docente-ne-add" placeholder="Número Exterior">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Carrera</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ni-add" name="form-usu-docente-ni-add" placeholder="Número Interior">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu4" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu4" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Menu 4</h3>
                    <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu5" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-form-add-docente" name="btn-form-add-docente" value="" disabled="true">Guardar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes validar cada bloque antes de realizar el cambio de visibilidad. Te sugiero crear reglas previamente para cada pestaña, de forma que puedas usar solo una función para las validaciones.

Lecturas recomendadas:

- [jQuery - Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) - Puede validar todo el formulario o solo lo que le proporciones en parámetros
- [jQuery - valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) - Devuelve el resultado de la validación

```js
let reglas = {
    '1': { rules: {
          "form-usu-docente-matricula-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nombre-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ap-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-am-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-curp-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ss-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-rfc-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nacion-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ife-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ln-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-fn-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-sexo-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nt-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-mailp-add": {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }

        },
        messages: {
          "form-usu-docente-matricula-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Matrícula"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nombre-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Nombre(s)"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ap-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Apellido Paterno"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-am-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Apellido Materno"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-curp-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar CURP"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ss-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Seguro Social"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-rfc-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar RFC"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nacion-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Nacionalidad"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ife-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar IFE"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ln-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Lugar de Nacimiento."
          },
          "form-usu-docente-fn-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Fecha de Nacimiento"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-sexo-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Sexo"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-nt-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Número de Tarjeta"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-mailp-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Correo Personal"
          }

        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
          element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        }},
    '2': { rules: {
          "form-usu-docente-estado-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-municipio-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-colonia-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-calle-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ne-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ni-add": {
            required: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-telefono-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-celular-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          },
          "form-usu-docente-cp-add": {
            required: true,
            number: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          "form-usu-docente-estado-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Estado"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-municipio-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Municipio"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-colonia-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Colonia"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-calle-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Calle"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ne-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Número Exterior"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-ni-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Número Interior"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-telefono-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Teléfono"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-celular-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Celular"
          },
          "form-usu-docente-cp-add": {
            required: "* Ingresar Código Postal"
          }
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
          error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
          element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
          $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        }}
  };

  function formValidate(num) {
    if(reglas[num]) {
        $('#modal-form-add-docente').validate(reglas[num]);
        // console.log($('#modal-form-add-docente').validate().settings.rules);
        let valid = $('#modal-form-add-docente').valid();
        console.log(valid);
        $('#modal-form-add-docente').validate().destroy();
        return valid;
    }
    return true;
}

  function wizard_docente(wizard){
        let [prevNext, current] = wizard.split('_menu');
        current = parseInt(current); // Forzar que sea entero
        if(current < 1 || current > 5) {
            alert('default'); // Eliminar la necesidad del switch
        }
        // Cuál es la siguiente pestaña a mostrar
        let next;
        
        if(prevNext == 'r') {
            // Es retroceso, no requiere validar formulario
            // Retroceder solo si la sección actual es mayor que uno
            next = (current > 1) ? current - 1 : current;
        } else {
            // Es avance, se debe validar formulario
            if(!formValidate(current)) {
                // Falló la validación, no ir al siguiente
                return;
            }
            // Pasar a siguiente pestaña solo si no estás en la última
            next = (current < 5) ? parseInt(current) + 1 : current;
        }
        if(next == current) {
          // Es el mismo, no es necesario hacer cambios
          return;
        }
        // Ocultar sección actual
        $('#menu' + current).removeClass('active');
        $('#menu' + current).removeClass('show');
        $('#m_menu' + current).removeClass('active');

        // Mostrar anterior o siguiente
        $('#menu' + next).addClass('active');
        $('#menu' + next).addClass('show');
        $('#m_menu' + next).addClass('active');
  }
```

```css
li a.active { color:blue; }
#menu1, #menu2, #menu3, #menu4, #menu5 {
  display:none;
}
.show {
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-docente">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="titulo-modal-docente">Agregar Administrador</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- form start -->
          <form id="modal-form-add-docente">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="container">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="m_menu1">Inf. Personal</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu2">Inf. Personal</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu3">Financiera</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu4">Academica</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="m_menu5">Dirección</a>
                  </li>
                </ul> 

                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade active show">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ID / Matrícula</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-matricula-add" name="form-usu-docente-matricula-add" placeholder="Matrícula" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nombre(s)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-nombre-add" name="form-usu-docente-nombre-add" placeholder="Nombre(s)">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apellido Paterno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ap-add" name="form-usu-docente-ap-add" placeholder="Apellido Paterno">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Apellido Materno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-am-add" name="form-usu-docente-am-add" placeholder="Apellido Materno">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CURP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-curp-add" name="form-usu-docente-curp-add" placeholder="CURP">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Seguro Social</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ss-add" name="form-usu-docente-ss-add" placeholder="Seguro Social">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">RFC</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-rfc-add" name="form-usu-docente-rfc-add" placeholder="RFC">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nacionalidad</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-nacion-add" name="form-usu-docente-nacion-add" placeholder="Nacionalidad">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">IFE</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ife-add" name="form-usu-docente-ife-add" placeholder="IFE">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Lugar de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ln-add" name="form-usu-docente-ln-add" placeholder="Lugar de Nacimiento">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-fn-add" name="form-usu-docente-fn-add" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Sexo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-sexo-add" name="form-usu-docente-sexo-add" placeholder="Sexo">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Número de Tarjeta</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-nt-add" name="form-usu-docente-nt-add" placeholder="Número de Tarjeta">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Correo Personal</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-mailp-add" name="form-usu-docente-mailp-add" placeholder="Correo Personal">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu1" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)" disabled="true"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu1" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Numero 2 -->
                  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Estado</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-estado-add" name="form-usu-docente-estado-add" placeholder="Estado">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Municipio</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" name="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" placeholder="Municipio">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Colonia</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" name="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" placeholder="Colonia">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Calle</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-calle-add" name="form-usu-docente-calle-add" placeholder="Calle">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Número Exterior</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ne-add" name="form-usu-docente-ne-add" placeholder="Número Exterior">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Número Interior</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ni-add" name="form-usu-docente-ni-add" placeholder="Número Interior">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Teléfono</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" name="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" placeholder="Teléfono">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Celular</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-celular-add" name="form-usu-docente-celular-add" placeholder="Celular">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">C.P.</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-cp-add" name="form-usu-docente-cp-add" placeholder="C.P.">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu2" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu2" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Numero 3 -->
                  <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tabulador</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-cp-add" name="form-usu-docente-cp-add" placeholder="C.P.">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Tabulador 2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" name="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" placeholder="Municipio">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Percepción Única</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" name="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" placeholder="Colonia">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Clave Bancaria</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-calle-add" name="form-usu-docente-calle-add" placeholder="Calle">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre Banco</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ne-add" name="form-usu-docente-ne-add" placeholder="Número Exterior">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Cuenta</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ni-add" name="form-usu-docente-ni-add" placeholder="Número Interior">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Actividad Primordial</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" name="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" placeholder="Teléfono">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Dirección de Actividad Primordial</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-celular-add" name="form-usu-docente-celular-add" placeholder="Celular">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Teléfono de Actividad Primordial</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" name="form-usu-docente-telefono-add" placeholder="Teléfono">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu3" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu3" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Numero 4 -->
                  <div id="menu4" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Titulo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-cp-add" name="form-usu-docente-cp-add" placeholder="C.P.">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Grado</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" name="form-usu-docente-municipio-add" placeholder="Municipio">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cedula</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" name="form-usu-docente-colonia-add" placeholder="Colonia">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Año de entrada</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-calle-add" name="form-usu-docente-calle-add" placeholder="Calle">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Turno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ne-add" name="form-usu-docente-ne-add" placeholder="Número Exterior">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Carrera</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-usu-docente-ni-add" name="form-usu-docente-ni-add" placeholder="Número Interior">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu4" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                          <input type="button" name="Siguiente" value="Siguiente" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="s_menu4" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="menu5" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <h3>Menu 4</h3>
                    <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                    <div class="form-row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <input type="button" name="Regresar" value="Regresar" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="r_menu5" onclick="wizard_docente(this.id)"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-form-add-docente" name="btn-form-add-docente" value="" disabled="true">Guardar</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: sabes que te amor verdad? Muchas gracias por tu apoyo!!!!

Comment: Hola buenos días. Ayer por la tarde termine de adaptar el código al proyecto que estoy realizando pero pasa que la primera pestaña si la valida pero y me cambia a la pestaña 2 hasta ahí todo correcto, pero cuando ya estoy en la pestaña 2 y le doy al siguiente sin haber llenado el formulario me manda a la pestaña 3 del wizard y no me esta validando la 2da pestaña. Actualizo mi pregunta para aplicar los cambios que hice. Saludos y bonito viernes

Comment: Actualice el código de JS ya que las modificaciones las palique ahí

Comment: solo modificaste la función de formValidate verdad? Aplique los cambios a esa función y ahora no me valida ni el primero. Actualizo mi pregunta aquí

Comment: ya la retorne y sigue sin validar

Comment: Sigue sin validar el primer formulario

Comment: No puedo, no se valida la pestaña 1 con los cambios y aplique todo correctamnete

Comment: Listo, actualice mi código

Comment: ya le estuve moviendo con otros ejemplos que e encontrado y no me quiere quedar

Comment: Llena con valores que cumplan las reglas y funciona sin problema.

Comment: lo que hice fue colocar esta linea de código $('#modal-form-add-docente').validate().destroy(); arriba, antes de que haga la validacion y ya quedo